# Safe to delete .lastcomm

Tags: web-server, unix, log-files, aix

I have a .lastcomm file that is >2GB is it safe to delete it? It's taking up a lot of room on the server and I can't find any documentation online related to it's log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use the lastcomm command regularly or depend on it then I wouldn't worry to blank this file, I wouldn't remove it as I'm not sure if it will recreate it's self.

To blank it you can simply run :

```
> .lastcomm
```

In the directory which the file is in.